# AWS Glue: Import JSON from Datalake(S3) with mixed data

Tags: json, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm currently struggling to understand how to create a data catalog of our data lake (=Source).

**Background:**

We have an event-driven architecture and started to store all events produced by our application to a data lake (S3 Bucket). Before the events are stored we sanitize them (remove sensitive information) and add an envelope around each event with some general data:

- event origin (which application generated the event)
- event type (what kind of event was generated)
- timestamp (when was the event generated)
- ...

With Kinesis Streams and Firehose, we batch those events together and store them as a JSON file in an S3 bucket. The bucket is structured like this:
/////

In there, we store the batched events with the envelope as JSON files. That means one JSON file contains multiple events:

```
{
  "origin": "hummingbird",
  "type": "AuthenticationFailed",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-30T18:24:13.868Z",
  "correlation_id": "2ff0c077-542d-4307-a58b-d6afe34ba748",
  "data": {
    ...
  }
}
{
  "origin": "hummingbird",
  "type": "PostingCreated",
  "timestamp": "2019-06-30T18:24:13.868Z",
  "correlation_id": "xxxx",
  "data": {
    ...
  }
}
```

The data object contains specific data of the events.

Now I thought I can use AWS Glue to hook into the raw data and use ETL Jobs to aggregate the event data. As I understood I need to have a data catalog for my source data and here is where I'm struggling with since the JSON always contains different events which are batched together. The standard "Crawler" cannot handle this..well it does but it creates non-sense schemas based on every JSON file.

**What I wanted to achieve:**

- Parse through the data lake to filter out events that I'm interested in
- Use the events that I'm interested in and do some transformation/aggregation/calculation with it
- Store results into our current Analytics RDS or wherever (enough for our purposes right now)
- Parse through newly events on a daily basis and insert/append/update that to our analytics rds

**My Questions I have:**

- What's the best way to use glue with our data lake?
- Are there possible ways to use crawlers with custom classifiers and some sort of filter together with our datalake?
- Do I need to transform the data even before, to actually be able to use AWS glue?

Answer (score 1):

let me give it a try.

1. Parse through the data lake to filter out events that I'm interested
   in
2. Use the events that I'm interested in and do some
   transformation/aggregation/calculation with it

--> You can flatten the json for each event, then export it into different S3 bucket. Refer to some python code here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

--> use Glue to crawl your new bucket & generate a new table schema, then in Athena you should be able to see it & do your filter/query/aggregation on top of the table. Once you're happy with the transformed data, you can further import it into Redshift or RDS.

3. Store results into our current Analytics RDS or wherever (enough for
   our purposes right now)

--> From Glue Catalog above, add Redshift/RDS connection, then use Python Spark (need some basic knowledge on working with dataframe) to load data into Redshift or RDS.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5952/read-enrich-and-transform-data-with-aws-glue-service/

4. Parse through newly events on a daily basis and insert/append/update
   that to our analytics rds

--> You can schedule your Glue crawler to discover new data from the new bucket.
Alternatively, Lambda is also a good option for this. Can use S3 object creation (thenew bucket with flattened json) to trigger a Lambda to , pre-process, ETL & then insert into Redshift/RDS (Using JDBC driver)